# failed to load ad:2 in android using admob

Tags: android

i have trying to get test ad on my device from last 3 weeks but still no ad.
plz help me .
my logcat details is:

```
01-04 14:09:22.099: D/WebView(1677): onSizeChanged - w:480 h:75
01-04 14:10:30.957: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1677): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
01-04 14:10:30.957: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1677): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
01-04 14:10:56.782: D/dalvikvm(3437): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 138K, 10% free 9738K/10759K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
01-04 14:10:56.922: D/dalvikvm(3437): GC_CONCURRENT freed 147K, 10% free 10109K/11143K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 131ms
01-04 14:10:56.922: D/dalvikvm(3437): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 66ms
01-04 14:10:57.022: I/dalvikvm(3437): Could not find method android.webkit.WebSettings.getDefaultUserAgent, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.g.a
01-04 14:10:57.022: W/dalvikvm(3437): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3091: Landroid/webkit/WebSettings;.getDefaultUserAgent (Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/lang/String;
01-04 14:10:57.022: D/dalvikvm(3437): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0011
01-04 14:10:57.112: D/dalvikvm(3437): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 244K, 10% free 10392K/11527K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
01-04 14:10:57.232: I/webclipboard(3437): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@41e6c6e0
01-04 14:10:57.252: I/Ads(3437): Starting ad request.
01-04 14:10:57.252: I/Ads(3437): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("11D834F405486C316220DC52A0BB7D6D") to get test ads on this device.
01-04 14:10:57.412: D/dalvikvm(3437): GC_CONCURRENT freed 193K, 10% free 10489K/11591K, paused 6ms+33ms, total 301ms
01-04 14:10:57.502: D/libEGL(3437): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_hawaii.so
01-04 14:10:57.512: D/(3437): mem_init ++
01-04 14:10:57.512: D/(3437): gHwMemAllocator client 3
01-04 14:10:57.512: D/(3437): **** Using ION allocator ****
01-04 14:10:57.512: D/(3437): registered SIGUSR1[10] for pid[3437]
01-04 14:10:57.512: D/(3437): HwMemAllocatorImpl Static Counters 0 0
01-04 14:10:57.512: D/(3437): HwMemAllocatorImpl[4acdad5c] totalDeviceAllocSize[0] totalFree[0] maxFree[0] in numSlabs[0]
01-04 14:10:57.512: D/(3437): mem_init 4acdad5c--
01-04 14:10:57.512: D/ION(3437): config: version(0x10000) secure(0xf000) 256M(0x22d) fast(0x608) hwwr(0x608)
01-04 14:10:57.512: D/(3437): Waiting for mm thread to come up
01-04 14:10:57.512: D/(3437): mm_device_thread starting
01-04 14:10:57.522: D/HAWAII_EGL(3437): eglCreateContext() config: 35 context: 0x4d983e40, VC context 1, Thread 3437
01-04 14:10:57.522: D/HAWAII_EGL(3437): Set SWAP INTERVAL 0
01-04 14:10:57.522: D/HAWAII_EGL(3437): eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4d57beb8, VC surface: 1, Thread: 3437
01-04 14:10:57.522: D/HAWAII_EGL(3437): eglMakeCurrent(0x4d983e40, 0x4d57beb8, 0x4d57beb8) Thread: 3437
01-04 14:10:57.522: D/OpenGLRenderer(3437): Enabling debug mode 0
01-04 14:10:57.583: V/webkit(3437): BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {41f6c018}
01-04 14:10:57.883: D/dalvikvm(3437): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads1156133905.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
01-04 14:10:58.183: D/dalvikvm(3437): DexOpt: --- END 'ads1156133905.jar' (success) ---
01-04 14:10:58.183: D/dalvikvm(3437): DEX prep '/data/data/com.example.myadtestapp/cache/ads1156133905.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 299ms
01-04 14:11:00.986: W/Ads(3437): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 1
01-04 14:11:00.996: I/dalvikvm(3437): Could not find method android.webkit.WebSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.o.a.<init>
01-04 14:11:00.996: W/dalvikvm(3437): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3104: Landroid/webkit/WebSettings;.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture (Z)V
01-04 14:11:00.996: D/dalvikvm(3437): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x004b
01-04 14:11:01.006: I/dalvikvm(3437): Could not find method android.webkit.WebView.evaluateJavascript, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.o.a.evaluateJavascript
01-04 14:11:01.016: W/dalvikvm(3437): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3114: Landroid/webkit/WebView;.evaluateJavascript (Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/webkit/ValueCallback;)V
01-04 14:11:01.016: D/dalvikvm(3437): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0016
01-04 14:11:01.036: V/webkit(3437): BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {41fc54a0}
01-04 14:11:01.036: I/webclipboard(3437): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@41fc5bd8
01-04 14:11:01.086: W/Ads(3437): Failed to load ad: 1
```

and main.java is:

```
package com.example.myadtestapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        // Request for Ads
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("4d08da7768519000")

    .build();

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

and activity_main.xml is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.myadtestapp.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
     <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
         xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1205981486869590/2185561060 "
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

and my mainfest.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myadtestapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
     <!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <!--This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services.-->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

plz help me to get out from this problem....

Answer (score 0):

Remove padding from parent layout.
To be exact, remove below 4 lines in your xml.

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Comment: I tried your code. It works after removing padding. I guess there is an additional space at the end of your adUnitId string. Remove that and try.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Google Play Services SDK?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Google Mobile Ads documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.html#ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST), "Failed to load ad: 1" means the ad unit ID was incorrect.

Get the proper add unit id. See: [Create an ad unit](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3052638?hl=en)